# Cross Compiling Objects with llvm-gcc-4.2

Tags: ios, macos, compiler-errors

I am trying to cross compile two object files with -static, but I'm getting an error message .

```
/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -o launchd launchd.o syscalls.o -static
-nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -Wl,-e,_main
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld_classic: launchd.o incompatible,
file contains unsupported type of section 3 (__TEXT,__picsymbolstub4) in load command 0 (must
specify "-dynamic" to be used)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If i try running it with the option -dynamic then I just get...

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -o
launchd launchd.o syscalls.o -dynamic -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -Wl,-e,_main
ld: warning: -force_cpusubtype_ALL will become unsupported for ARM architectures
Undefined symbols for architecture arm:
"_cp", referenced from:
  _main in launchd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone have any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you might be missing an object file (with `_cp` in it).

Comment: I don't use anything called _cp in file though.  I'm using a cp command in my launchd.c file though (I guess that's what it's referring to?).  I noticed if I take it out, then it works.

Comment: No the 'cp' command will be in a string won't it, so it's not that.

Comment: actually no, the code I have is like:                                 cp("/files/hello", "/mnt/usr/bin/hello"); I'm copying the code write out of a book so I know it's not completely wrong.  I'm thinking that maybe it has something to do with the version of llvm-gcc compiler?

Comment: And you haven't created a `cp()` function?  You have got to be kidding, right?

Comment: yeah...I'm using chown and chmod the same way, and I'm not getting errors with those.

Comment: `chown()` and `chmod()` are system calls (functions provided by the O/S).  `cp()` isn't.

Comment: Did you resolve this?